# Is there an operating system named Linux?

Tags: linux

I found that the operating system used in my college labs to learn Linux or Unix is Ubuntu. Is there an operating system named "Linux"?

Comment: Ubuntu is not an operating system. It is a **distribution** that includes  linux as its kernel.

Comment: @Anthon The two are not contradictory.

Comment: What part of the Wikipedia article did you not understand?

Answer (score 6):

Linux is a *family* of operating systems, like the Windows family or Mac OS family or Unix family.

Beyond this, there are different Linuxes, Unixes, Windows, ...

In the Linux/Unix world, different sub-families are called distributions.

Some examples :

- Linux : Ubuntu, Debian, RedHat, Suse, CenOS, ArchLinux, ... and [many more](http://distrowatch.com/).
- Unix : Solaris, AIX, HP-UX, ...
- Windows : Windows Home, Windows Server, Windows Phone
- Mac OS : OSX, iOS

By the way, Ubuntu is a good user friendly Linux distribution to start with.

Comment: One thing to add is that "Windows" OSs aren't called "Windows", instead you get names like "Windows 7", "Windows XP", and "Windows 95". Just like there is no Linux distro called "Linux" there is no Windows OS called "Windows"

Comment: Technically, Linux is a kernel, but it is also informally used to refer to a family of operating systems which make use of the Linux kernel, sometimes also referred to as Linux distributions. Any answer should mention that, in my opinion. Whether one should use Linux to refer to these operating systems is a source of some dispute. Having said that, surely this is a dupe.

Answer (score 4):

Linux, by itself, is not an operating system, it's a **kernel**.
If you do not know what a kernel is, consider it as the ham in the sandwich which upper bread slice in what you see on the software and the lower bread slice is the hardware.

When one talks about **Linux**, he's probably not talking about the kernel though, and might be referring to **GNU/Linux** (the association of the Linux kernel with the GNU OS), and calling it just *Linux* is then a mistake - yet a common one.

So one should say:

> **Ubuntu** is the most famous GNU/Linux distribution.

instead of

> **Ubuntu** is Linux

which, *stricto sensu*, doesn't mean anything.

Another interesting thing is that saying that GNU/Linux is a Unix system is another mistake, as *GNU* stands for *GNU's Not Unix*. GNU only reuses elements from Unix systems, without being one by itself; it's as much Unix as Mac OS X.

Comment: This is purely an opinion piece. You should not state it as if it was absolute truth. Most of the world calls the operating system “Linux”, not because they don't know better, but because they know better.

Comment: But Mac OS X *is* Unix; they paid their money.

Comment: Also, the “not Unix” in GNU is Hurd. Linux is as much Unix as OSX (in factual terms — in legal terms OSX paid to get the stamp but nobody's paid for a Linux distribution to get the stamp).

Comment: @Gilles I happen to agree with the answer, but: No; I do not need another long debate on the **several** facets of this issue. Been there, done that. have t-shirt. Do you want one? :-P

Comment: "operating system" and "kernel" are the same thing